# How to identify and de-enque conflicting scripts on wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm creating a website on WordPress using https://understrap.com/ theme and https://lifterlms.com
When the plugin lifterlms is activated, my navbar is acting improperly on mobile.
With the chrome dev tools on mobile view, if I click to open the menu, it opens briefly and closes automatically.
Testing on my phone with a live link, clicking on the toggle opens the menu but don't close.
Here's a video to illustrate what's happening https://youtu.be/O0DpAmoZz_c

To replicate the problem:

- Install understrap theme https://understrap.com/
- Install and activate understrap child theme
- https://understrap.com/understrap-child-themes/
- Create some pages
- Create a menu and ad pages to it
- Install and activate lifterLms
- view website in mobile view with dev tools
- Click menu toggle

I contacted lifterlms team but unfortunately they will not be able to help in an acceptable delay for me.

They told me to:

You could try de-enqueing the offending conflicts in your child theme's functions.php file.

So my question is, how should I proceed to identify the conflicting script?

Any help would be appreciated.

Expected Behavior
menu to open/close on click on mobile as it should

Actual Behavior
Menu rapidly close on mobile when clicked

Answer (score 0):

"if I click to open the menu, it opens briefly and closes automatically." - This may be caused by having the same handler installed twice. The click will invoke the handler twice. The first invocation opens the menu. The second invocation closes the menu. Hence, "it opens briefly and closes automatically". One way the same handler can be installed twice is having two versions of the same library loaded. I suspect a desktop browser version and mobile browser version of the same library. Each version will attach its own handler. Using the browsers' development tools you can view all the handlers - check for any duplicate handler - or view the list of loaded JavaScript - check for duplicate files. As a last resort you can not load individual JavaScript files by just renaming them temporarily and see if that solves your problem. All of this is conjecture and may be totally unrelated to this problem so you need to investigate further.

Comment: Thank you @magenta for your reply. I don't know enough the dev tools to use them to see all handlers, I will make more research to be able to find if I have duplicates.
Any other tips on what to do would be appreciated.

Comment: The browser development tools require a relatively small investment in time and effort and makes solving problems like this sometimes (but not always) easy. So my tip is learn how to use the browser developer tools. They are quite user friendly and indispensable.